# Can a mature pine trunk curve in a few months?

Tags: trees, pines

I am in the "piney woods" temperate rainforest of east Texas. Three months ago I had a large oak (18 inch diameter, 70 feet tall) removed. It was about 4 feet south from the patio and 12 feet from the house. There is a large shortleaf pine (24 inch diameter, 100 feet tall) six feet south of where the oak had been, so 10 feet from the patio and 18 feet from the house. (Yes, I made a big mistake saving too many trees when the house was built.)

I just  noticed the pine has curved to the north, toward the house. The trunk leans a little to the south, but now I notice it curves about 15 feet to the north, starting at about 50 feet up. I did not notice it three months ago when I looked up to watch them cut out the top of the oak. These southern pines are basically straight power poles, so a curved one looks all the more peculiar. How could this happen in a few months? It is curving away from the sun.

---

The "tree guy" has been cutting trees in the area for 40 years says "no problem". He has cut a dozen trees on my lot and I trust him; of course he would cut it if I want him to. He is a serious tree guy and has among his equipment a work basket on a 100 ft. boom , unfortunately it will not reach the tree in question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not going to help future visitors and it has been answered by the OP, that it was a mistake.  That is, the question is not valid.  And any answers here will be speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Not likely, apparently I did not look straight up outside my door that often and that is a poor position to observe the degree of straightness. So when I was in a position to see the angle, I did not have a good reference basis with which to compare it. Apparently it has always been curved. It still is unsettling to see it curve back over the house.